# setting up apache behind a forward proxy

Tags: apache, proxypass

I have an Internet connection which is behind a forward proxy.I have to use the proxy server ip address & port No. to connect to the internet.I have installed apache web server in my machine.The apache is configured to use ProxyPass (meaning - it has to fetch documents from an external site).But the forward proxy blocks any such request.How do I set up apache to use the forward proxy server's ip address & port No to access external urls.

Comment: Again I got the answer just add `ProxyRemote * http://192.168.10.1:8080` in httpd.conf .But I couldn't get it to work for   `ProxyRemote  /uploads/ http://192.168.10.1:8080`.

Answer (score 4):

If you wanted to proxy say a site from your machine through the corporate proxy, like I recently had to do for a Centos installation, you would use this in your apache config:

```
ProxyPass       /centos1/  http://ftp.riken.jp/

ProxyPassReverse /centos1/ http://ftp.riken.jp/

ProxyRemote http://ftp.riken.jp/ http://{corporate proxy here}:{corporate proxy port}
```