# Setting up Apache to use an internal Proxy Server( Proxy Chaining? )

Tags: apache, mod-proxy, proxypass

I have a situation where I need to route requests to Apache through an internal Proxy Server before redirecting to an external Site, the setup is something like this:

```
Browser Request --> Apache --> Internal Proxy Server --> External Site
```

Without the Proxy Server I accomplished the redirect using a rewrite handled as a Proxy( [P] )

```
RewriteRule ^/somepath/(.*) http://www.externalsite.com/$1 [P,QSA,L]
```

I found [setting up apache behind a forward proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7554225/setting-up-apache-behind-a-forward-proxy) which looked like it was what I wanted to setup, and suggested I try the following directives:

```
ProxyPass /somepath/ http://www.externalsite.com/
ProxyPassReverse /somepath/ http://www.externalsite.com/
ProxyRemote  http://www.externalsite.com/ http://internal.proxy.ip.addy:8080
```

When I set this up I got a 503 and the following Apache log entries:

```
[Thu Apr 11 07:47:14 2013] [debug] mod_proxy_http.c(1973): proxy: HTTP: serving URL http://www.externalsite.com/somefile.html
[Thu Apr 11 07:47:14 2013] [debug] proxy_util.c(2011): proxy: HTTP: has acquired connection for (www.externalsite.com)
[Thu Apr 11 07:47:14 2013] [debug] proxy_util.c(2067): proxy: connecting http://www.externalsite.com/somefile.html to www.externalsite.com:80
[Thu Apr 11 07:47:14 2013] [debug] proxy_util.c(2193): proxy: connected http://www.externalsite.com/somefile.html to internal.proxy.ip.addy:8080
[Thu Apr 11 07:47:14 2013] [debug] proxy_util.c(2444): proxy: HTTP: fam 2 socket created to connect to www.externalsite.com
[Thu Apr 11 07:47:35 2013] [error] (OS 10060)A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.  : proxy: HTTP: attempt to connect to internal.proxy.ip.addy:8080 (www.externalsite.com) failed
```

Nothing was logged in the proxy server logs, and I know the proxy server works if I set it explicitly in the browser and load that externalsite.com

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up being a vmware IP address issue when connecting to the proxy... The above directives do seem to correctly proxy apache through to the proxy server.