# Apache proxypass does not allow HTTP_POST

Tags: apache, ssl, reverse-proxy, proxypass

I have many server aliases on my server. All of them need to post to original site to get results from HTTP POSTS. I can't get the posts to work. The weird thing is Ajax calls DO WORK but not HTTP_POST. This problem is driving me insane. Can somebody help me please ?

Here is my Apache vhost for my site :

```
ServerName xxx-mtl.xxx.net
    ServerAlias xxx-mtg.xxx.net xxx-est.xxx.net xxx-prd.xxx.net xxx-mau.xxx.net xxx-lan.xxx.net xxx-lav.xxx.net xxx-cot.xxx.net  xxx-cha.xxx.net xxx-bas.xxx.net xxx-abi.xxx.net xxx-out.xxx.net

    SSLProxyEngine On
    ProxyRequests Off

    ProxyPass        / https://xxx.xxx.net:443/
    ProxyPassReverse / https://xxx.xxx.net:443/
    ProxyRemote      * https://127.0.0.1:3128

    SetEnv proxy-sendchunked 1

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/conf/star.xxx.net.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/conf/star.xxx.net.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/httpd/conf/gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt

    LogLevel warn
    ErrorLog logs/xxx.net-error_log
    CustomLog logs/xxx.net-access_log common
```

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

```
ProxyPass        / https://xxx.xxx.net:443/
ProxyPassReverse / https://xxx.xxx.net:443/
ProxyRemote      https://127.0.0.1:3128 *
```

Ref : [setting up apache behind a forward proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7554225/setting-up-apache-behind-a-forward-proxy)

try proxy remote * last